# Creating API For Accessing New Website

Tags: orange, api

Is there a way to add a API in Orange Data Mining Tool to access a new website? An example would be can I create and add an API for CNN or MSNBC or FOXNEWS? Currently in Orange in the text mining add-on they only have a couple of websites plus twitter. I am looking to add some of my own API to text mine.